# Generate cloud formation template from DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a DynamoDB table which needs to be replicated to different environments. The best way to manage the table is by having a CloudFormation template so a script could create the table based on the template. Given the table exists already I was wondering if it's possible to generate e template for the existing table, any thoughts? Couldn't find much in google...

The template would look something like this:

```
"Resources": {
    "CustomerTable": {
      "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties" : {
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "customerId",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "customerId",
            "AttributeType": "N"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
          "ReadCapacityUnits" : { "Ref": "CustomerReadCapacity" },
          "WriteCapacityUnits" : { "Ref": "CustomerWriteCapacity" }
        },
        "TableName" : "customer"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CloudFormer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to generate a CloudFormation template from existing resources in an AWS account.

However, the template that is generated will not be linked in any way to your existing resources. CloudFormer will generate a template that is a *copy* of your existing resources. Using the template that gets generated will create a new CloudFormation stack with new resources.

There is no way to take existing resources and get them included in a CloudFormation stack. If you want your resources to be managed by CloudFormation, then they need to be created by CloudFormation in the first place.

Comment: Fantastic, let me give it a go!

Comment: cloudFormer is straightforward to use but makes you jump through a few hoops (create a VM, choose the resources you want to export, etc). A simpler solution (with some manual copy-paste) is to get the layout of the table using the describe-table of aws CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html). Then you can keep the fields you need (AttributeDefinitions and so forth) and put a Cloudformation skeleton around them