# Creation of AWS Cloud Formation Template from Existing DynamoDB Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

How to create **aws cloud formation** template from existing **DynamoDB tables**. I've explored **CloudFormer Tool**, but didn't find any way to generate a template from tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982832/generate-cloud-formation-template-from-dynamodb-table

Comment: I had checked that link before posting question, but unfortunately didn't get it done. Thanks @A

Comment: what is the error you run into?

Comment: I am not able to find the method to generate cloud formation template from existing DynamoDB tables. I've tried cloud formation template diagram editor, but can see only general dynamodb table.

Comment: any solution to this @ZeeshanTariq